# cgcreate inside Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.12

RUN <<EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y cgroup-tools
EOF

WORKDIR /opt
COPY main.py main.py

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

Inside "main.py", I have this line

```
env_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
cgroup_name = f"exec_env_{env_uuid}"

subprocess.run(["cgcreate", "-g", f"memory:/{cgroup_name}"], check=True)
```

When I run it, with the command

```
docker buildx build --progress=plain --tag mytag . && docker run --privileged mytag
```

I get the error

```
cgcreate: can't create cgroup /exec_env_181a6832-1bba-4a3e-b3e8-2209cddd90ca: Device or resource busy
```

My question is: Is it possible to create cgroups within a Docker container? If so, what is needed?

Comment: Docker uses cgroups as part of its own isolation mechanisms.  I can't speak authoritatively, but it wouldn't surprise me if this wasn't possible, and you need a full virtual machine here.

Comment: Indeed, I was considering the possibility of "nested" cgroups, similar to nested virtualization.